# How to color geom_rect() background rectangles according to a continuous numeric variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R ggplot2, how to use `scale_fill_gradient()` or `scale_fill_gradient2()` with `geom_rect()` to color the background panel according to a numeric variable? I know this is possible as I achieved this about a year ago using code similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(xmin = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
                 xmax = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                 var = runif(5))
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_rect(data = df, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                                    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                                    fill = var))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "orange", mid = "white", high = "blue", midpoint = 0.5)
gg
```

However, this doesn't work anymore, or more likely I am forgetting some key part of the code I need.

In the reproducible example above, the fill variable is random. In reality my fill variable will increase smoothly from 0 to 1, so the rectangles will likewise change color smoothly.

Comment: looks like with `ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf` doesn't work. I tried `ymin = 0, ymax = 1` and it works. Do you need the bars to go to Inf?

Comment: @Edo Thanks, that was it. Note that `ymax = Inf` works. Just can't have `ymin = -Inf`. I'm pretty sure `ymin = -Inf` worked fine the last time I tried this about a year ago.

Comment: I do remember that too actually.. You should check the code or the updates on ggplot2